# SELECT a row that throw 'duplicate entry' during MySQL INSERT in a single query

Tags: mysql

How can I retrieve a row that throw 'duplicate entry' during insertion

**`mtable` structure**

```
 email  varchar[50] unique
 name   varchar[30]
```

I am trying to insert a row in to `mtable`, my requirement is to get the entire row if the email exist otherwise it will insert new values into the table and return insert success

Comment: just try this select * from mtable where email='example@example.com' check row count if it is greater than 0 email already exists .if not greater than 0 email not exists

Comment: What about simply firing a select query with this email?

Comment: @JYoThI can i use it in single query during insertion

Comment: @YourCommonSense I don't  know the email address already inserted ,when i try to insert a row , it will return that row if email is duplicate.did you get my point?

Comment: How on the earth you don't know it if you are trying to insert it right now?!

Comment: @YourCommonSense my aim is to insert an email to a table ,if the corresponding row exist then it will return existing row ,otherwise it will insert values and return insert success

Answer (score 0):

Just try this `select * from mtable where email='example@example.com'` check row count if it is greater than 0 email already exists .if not greater than 0 email not exists

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM mtable WHERE email=? ");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $get_result =$stmt->get_result();
    $row_count= $get_result->num_rows;
    if($row_count>0)
    {
       //email already exists 
       $result = $get_result->fetch_assoc();
       print_r($result);
    }
    else
    {
        $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("insert into mtable(email,name)values(?,?)");
        $stmt1->bind_param('ss',$email,$name);
        $stm1->execute();
        $row_count1= $stmt1->affected_rows;
        if($row_count1>0)
        {
          echo "inserted successfully";
        }
         $stmt1->close();
         $conn->close();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response,I Know this is possible with multiple query ,I want to know is it possible in a single query.

Comment: i think it's not possible with single query . and i'm not sure about it @CLIFFORDPY

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of code is your concern, then consider PDO, as it will take you less code for the two queries than mysqli for one

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM mtable WHERE email=? ");
$stmt->execute([$email]);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if(!$row)
{
    $conn->prepare("insert into mtable(email,name)values(?,?)")->execute([$email,$name]);
}
```